# Holding the PI in reset?

Tags: power, reset

Is it safe to hold the pi in reset (via run/p5) indefinitely? If so, will it save on power consumption?

Comment: I have had a look in the ARM datasheets, but still not sure whether it will influence power consumption. For one thing, not all clocks seem to be stopped when in reset. Other than that I would not expect something to happen, if hold in reset indef.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is safe. I tested it on my B and A and it seemed to be fine. It didn't seem to save power though.

Answer (score 2):

It will never damage the Pi by holding it in reset mode.  It isn't the best idea if you want to save on power consumption.