# How to disable boot when plugged to power?

Tags: gpio, boot, power, power-supply, power-management

I want to disable boot of raspberry pi 4B when plugged to power
I have searched a lot and found a similar [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61588/disable-boot-on-plug-in-power-cable), which gives a short and suspicious answer to this problem. If two RUN pins(holes) connect together will it disable auto boot process when plugged to power and will it damage raspberry pi board if I connect that pins forever?

Comment: What model Pi? WHY - this is how the Pi is designed? What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: @Milliways pi is 4B. I want to disable auto boot when plugged to power.

Comment: This fails to explain WHY. It can be done but there seems no point. There are many other possibilities for Pi4 (which you could find) - but this depends on WHY you would WANT to do it.

Comment: @Milliways I want to add on/off bittun to my pi and turn on and off only that push button. How to do it?

Comment: The only solution is the one in the duplicate, which if you actually read through that and [this linked question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39380/5538), you get an answer to *"will it damage raspberry pi board if I connect that pins forever"* -> No (but it's implied this will use more power than when it is shut down and left in a stopped state).  However, obviously it will never run that way, so doing it permanently is pointless....

Comment: ...You could get a button that locks down, then when clicked again comes up.  But attaching a power switch is technically not your question -- and note that one has been much done here already too, but if you find anything that is unclear to you, feel free to ask something more specific.

Comment: @goldilocks yes ther is another problem also. On my pi 4 there are 3 headers (run, ground and global enable, which 2 pins I must connect together to get necessary functionality?) Or I must connect another pin to that RUN header?

Comment: @goldilocks so I want to know which pins I must connect?

Comment: Is that what you want to know?  If so and you can't find the answer yourself, than *ask a more specific question*, by which I mean via the "Ask Question" button top right.  We don't have a running discussion style here; comments are just for clarifying the actual question at the top, not for an open ended series of follow up questions. Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.